# I need plugin for FireFox to send highligted text to some URL

Tags: firefox, plugins

I need simple plugin for FireFox with following functionality:

Highlight text or image on the page, right click on it and choose something like "Send to URL" option. Then text is sent with POST message to URL which is provided in setting.

Is there any plugin, which can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selected text could be sent to a URL with the following [bookmarklet](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/bookmarklets-perform-common-web-page-tasks):

```
javascript: function postClipboard(){
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "http://www.example.com";
    http.open("POST", url, true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.send(window.getSelection());
}
postClipboard()
```